# Number of related users to projects in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have 2 documents (Projects and Users) and 1 edge (is member to) where 1 User --is member to--> multiple Projects.
I want to number of related Users to every Project, returning list of Project.name and count of users.

I'm able to get count but with document _ids and want to return the keys with Project.name:

```
for a in is_member_of
collect project = a._from into groups
sort count(groups) desc
return {"project": project, "membersInProject": count(groups)}
```

Returns:

| project | membersInProject |
| --- | --- |
| Projects/6397 | 6 |
| Projects/6398 | 4 |
| Projects/6399 | 4 |
| Projects/5999 | 2 |

I want project column to contain Project.name instead of Project._id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

```
FOR m IN is_member_to
  FOR p IN Projects FILTER p._id == m._to
    FOR u IN Users FILTER u._id == m._from
COLLECT x = p.name INTO groups
RETURN {"project": x, "count":COUNT(groups)}
```